# Highcharts Weird Vertical Lines

Tags: highcharts

I don't understand why there are all these strange vertical lines in this form:

[image: weird graph]

Here is the JS Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/oz73d3gg/

Code:

```
Highcharts.chart('js-chart-rating-month', {

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Ratings'
    },

    xAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,

    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Ratings'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            label: {
                connectorAllowed: true
            }

        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Ratings',
        data: [[2006,9], [2007,6], [2007,8], [2008,9], [2009,9], [2009,7], [2009,9], [2009,10], [2010,9], [2010,9], [2010,10], [2010,8], [2011,8], [2011,8], [2011,10], [2011,5], [2011,9], [2011,9], [2012,10], [2012,9], [2012,9], [2012,10], [2012,10], [2013,9], [2013,9], [2013,9], [2013,9], [2014,8], [2014,10], [2014,10], [2015,9], [2015,9], [2015,8], [2015,10], [2015,8], [2016,10], [2016,10], [2016,9], [2016,9], [2016,10], [2016,10], [2016,8], [2017,10], [2017,9], [2017,10], [2017,9], [2017,10], [2017,8] ]
    }],

    responsive: {
        rules: [{
            condition: {
                maxWidth: 500
            },
            chartOptions: {
                legend: {
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        }]
    }

});
```

Also, the points seem to be missing like in this graph:
[image: Good Graph]

Any ideas?  I am drawing a blank here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple value for the same year so you must clean you `data` :

```
series: [{
        name: 'Ratings',
        data: [... [2017,10], [2017,9], [2017,10], [2017,9], [2017,10], [2017,8] ] // Only 1 value for each year
    }],
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/oz73d3gg/1/)